# Data not saving permanently in table by LINQ/SQL

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, database, linq-to-sql

I'm trying to insert data into SQL table through LINQ. But data isn't going to save permanently in the table. Here I'm creating DataContext Object

```
 PanelDataContext db= new PanelDataContext();
```

I have a table "Point"..And here is my LINQ query to insert the data into the table.

```
  private void Insert_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
  {
     Point point= new Point();
     point.name=txtName.Text;
     point.ip= txtIp.Text;
     point.port= txtPort.Text;
     db.Points.InsertOnSubmit(point);
     db.SubmitChanges();
     status.Content= @"Entered Successfully"
   }
```

When I run the application there is no any error by Visual Studio. And I can retrieve that data on run time programmatically. But when I close the application and reopen it then I can't access any previous data and table is also empty. Your help would be highly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: How did you test this? Which database do you connect to? Are you connecting to a user instance database perhaps, in your `bin/Debug` folder? In that case it's probably getting replaced each time you build your application

Comment: It's Service-based Database provided by Visual Studio. It can be access through LINQ.. I can manually enter data into the the table and can access in the WPF application through LINQ. And it stores permanently but when I try to insert data by LINQ query through application data isn't going to store permanently. It can be access run time only

Comment: Chances are that due to an exception when saving, your changes are being rolled back. Analyse the output window to see if anything comes out when you execute the Submit changes.